# Package ilog doesn't exist even after adding cplex.jar to lib

Tags: java, cplex, ilog

I was following the instructions in this [github repo](https://github.com/JohnDickerson/KidneyExchange), downloaded the free version of cplex, and added cplex.jar from CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib and put it into KidneyExchange/lib. I also added `-Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx` to VM options in IntelliJ.

When I tried to run some test code, though, I got multiple variations on this error `java: package ilog.concert does not exist`

I'm using IntelliJ on a mac, and got cplex.jar from the free version of cplex studio on IBMs website. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not set the classpath correctly. First of all, try with an absolute path. Also note that the classpath must contain the `cplex.jar` *file*, not just the directory that contains the JAR.

Maybe you have set your classpath in a way that does not apply to IntelliJ. In order to debug this, you can add code like this to your program (before trying to import anything from `ilog`):

```
System.out.println("classpath: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Make sure this contains the `cplex.jar` file.